# control vb.net program from Acrobat Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, pdf, acrobat

I am writing a vb.NET program to handle documentation for my company. It has a database with equipment info and documentation status, and uploads and downloads forms to a server.  I have most of it complete except for how to have the user finish filling out the form, signing it and having the program automatically upload the form and updating the database that the form is complete.

I tried opening the pdf in a window within the program using the COM object available in Visual Studio, but when I clicked on Fill and sign it said Fill and sign is not available in browser mode so that seems to be a no go.

What I am wondering now is if I have the program open the PDF in Acrobat, is there a way for me to have a "submit" button in the PDF that once clicked will trigger the .NET program to begin the Save process and run the rest of the code?